# Why integration by long division gives different answer than using u substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

So, after solving this question, I got two different answers? and I don't think it's supposed to be this way?

> Evaluate the integral $$\int \frac{x^2+2}{x+2} dx$$

Using polynomial long division, I get
$$\frac{x^2}2-2x+6\ln|x+2|+C,$$
but using substitution, I get
$$\frac{(x+2)^2}2-4(x+2)+6\ln|x+2|+C.$$

Comment: The second solution is the same as the first, up to a difference in $C$.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2816513/same-integration-with-2-different-answers

Comment: Also related: [\[1\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1899165/integration-different-answers-from-two-methods), [\[2\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109880/different-answer-for-integral-for-two-different-methods), [\[3\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320823/can-an-indefinite-integral-have-multiple-answers-besides-the-c/320825), [\[4\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3041933/why-does-using-u-substitution-give-a-different-answer)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453558/getting-different-answers-when-integrating-using-different-techniques

Comment: They differ only by an arbitrary constant.  First one is $x^2-2x+6, $ and the second one is $x^2-2x-6 $

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\frac{(x+2)^2}2-4(x+2)+6\ln|x+2|+C=\frac{x^2}2-2x-6+6\ln|x+2|+C=$$

$$=\frac{x^2}2-2x+6\ln|x+2|+(C-6)=\frac{x^2}2-2x+6\ln|x+2|+C_1$$

therefore the two results are the same up to a constant which is not essential, indeed in both cases

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x^2}2-2x+6\ln|x+2|+C\right)=\frac{x^2+2}{x+2}$$

Comment: Yes of course! Thanks

Comment: So $$\frac{x^2-4x-12}{2}$$ is same as $$ \frac{x^2-4x}{2}$$ ?

Comment: @JameelKhamis No, they are not the same.  However, they only differ by a constant: $$\frac{x^2 - 4x - 12}{2} = \frac{x^2 - 4x}{2} + \underbrace{(-6)}_{=C}. $$

Answer (score -1):

Your answers differ by a constant. Therefore, if one of them is correct, the other one is correct too.

Comment: so, that -12 won't make any difference to the answer, correct?

Comment: Correct. For instance, both $x$ and $x-12$ are such that their derivative is $1$.